# Issue related to method arguments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, arguments

I am facing some problem related to arguments passing in rails. From my controller I want to send a variable as an argument to the request handler job. But I am sure that I am doing something wrong about the variables and arguments.
Student is the model name. Actually the students table contains some records.
I am facing the following problem.

formal argument can not be an instance variable.

Here is my code:

My app/controllers/students_controller.rb file is:-

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

attr_accessor :xmodel
def new
    @student=Student.new
    @students=Student.all
end

def create
    @student=Student.new(u_params)
    @student.set_insertbool_field

    xmodel=Student.last
    RequestHandlerJob.doit_later(:xmodel)

    if @student.save
        redirect_to new_student_path
    end
end


 def u_params
   params.require(:student).permit(:id , :firstname, :lastname)
 end

end
```

My app/jobs/request_handler_job.rb file is:

```
class RequestHandlerJob < ActiveJob::Base
queue_as :default

self.queue_adapter = :sidekiq


def doit_later(:xmodel) 
 # Do something later
 @extract_bool=:xmodel.inserted_bool
  if @extract_bool == 1
    redirect_to new_student_path , :notice => "Inserted and Queued"

  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I am facing problem probably just because of "model' variable

Comment: Just an assumption, why are you passing symbol `:xmodel` instead of variable `xmodel` defined earlier?
Also, afaik, pass an instance to sidekiq is a bad practice. In common you should send an id. `RequestHandlerJob.doit_later(Student.last.id)` and then in your worker just fetch needed record `Student.find(student_id)`

Comment: It was showing undefined method "doit_later"... I am new in rails so I dont know what should I pass as argument ? is it :xmodel or just model. Previously I passes @model but there was error formal argument can not be an instance variable.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you'd like to implement with `ActiveJob`? What is a use case? I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: Actually I want to implement a job queue. More precisely there is a student table in database and I can insert data into the table from a form in user interface and after clicking the submit button it will show the content of the database in same webpage. Now I want to implement a queue in between. The insert request will be queued and then the server will serve it from queue.That is why I have implemented job

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to do the next:

```
# app/controllers/students_controller.rb
def create
  @student=Student.new(u_params)
  @student.set_insertbool_field

  RequestHandlerJob.perform_later(@student.id) if @student.extract_bool == 1

  if @student.save
    flash[:notice] = "Inserted and Queued"
    render @student
  else
    render 'new'  
  end
end


# app/jobs/request_handler_job.rb

class RequestHandlerJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(student_id)
    # extract_bool is == 1
    student = Student.find(student_id)
    # do some hard work here
  end
end
```

Please keep in mind that you can't redirect user form a background job, because it runs in the background and there is no user session and browser.

You can just make some hard work there and then notify your user through websocket or somehow else.

Here is a related [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast)